# Regular expression to match lines which are preceded and succeeded by blank lines?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which looks like

> This is a line which is a continuation from above .......
>
> This is line I want to match ....
>
> This is another line I want to match ....
>
> This is yet another line I want to match ....
>
> This is some regular text. Blah ...
>   Continuation of the regular text above ...

I want to "compact" lines preceded and succeeded by blank lines. Like this

> This is line I want to match ....
>   This is another line I want to match ....
>   This is yet another line I want to match ....
>
> This is some regular text. Blah ...
>   Continuation of the regular text above

I tried to match the lines which are preceded and succeeded by newline by using

`re.findall(r'\n\n[\w ]+\n\n')`

but that failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know how to match the lines you wanted to match, and just want to know the way to compact these lines?

Comment: I do not know how match; after matching I think I can use backreferencing to eliminate the extra newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCRE isn't available in Python, so you'd have to go with something like the following:

```
/(?=\r?\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85)(\r?\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85)(.+(\r?\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85))(?=\r?\n|\x0b|\f|\r|\x85)/g
```

Python Live Demo: http://regex101.com/r/xL8bF1 (Please see [pcrepattern specification](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/pcrepattern.html#newlineseq) for the complex line feed stuff)

PCRE regular expression that should do what you want:

```
/(?=\R)\R(.+\R)(?=\R)/g
```

PCRE (PHP) Live Demo: http://regex101.com/r/aO8yA7

*PS:* Make use of the *visualize whitespace* feature over at regex101 for better understanding of the substitution result.

Comment: You might want to add an extra check for '\r' for Windows systems.

Comment: Extended to match any kind of Unicode line feed character.

Comment: +1 for the approach and the regex101.com demo; perhaps it should be `(.+)`, though; sounds like the OP only wants to match around non-empty lines.

Comment: Extended further to exclude lines that only consist of whitespace.

Comment: The `[\r?\n]` doesn't work as intended: this will match only one character, namely any of the following 3: `\r`, `?`, `\n`. Not sure there is a solution with a look-behind assertion - other than determining the actual newline sequence up front by analyzing the input data. Note that look-_ahead_ assertions are _not_ subject to the same fixed-width limitation.

Comment: Fixed the Python one, will fix the PCRE right away. I'm also including the line feed around the line as you did in your answer, as this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks, but `[\r\n|\n]` again will only match **1** char., including a literal `|`, not a *sequence* - you probably meant to use `(\r\n|\n)`, but that again violates the fixed-length look-behind constraint. Now that you're only matching *1* newline with the look-behind, an easy way out that's probably good enough is to only match `\n` - whether preceded by an `\r` or not.

Comment: Aaaaannnnd updated again after extensive testing. Using lookaheads only is doing the trick. Also updated the Python one to handle *all* kinds of line feeds. Let me know if you have any further ideas to improve it.

Comment: Good idea re switch to look-ahead. `[^\s*]` doesn't work as intended and two of the newline-matching expressions are still in `[]` instead of `()`; I'll stop now, as this comment thread is getting looong.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Fleshgrinder's excellent approach to perform the substitution desired:

```
re.sub(r'(?=\n)\n(.+)\n(?=\n)', r'\1\n', inputString)
```

If you also need to make it work with input that has `\r\n` line endings:

```
re.sub(r'(?=\r?\n)\r?\n(.+)(\r?\n)(?=\r?\n)', r'\1\2', inputString)
```

Assuming a Unix system and an input file named `in.txt`, you can test it from the command line as follows:

```
python -c \
  "import re,sys; print re.sub(r'(?=\n)\n(.+)\n(?=\n)', r'\1\n', sys.argv[1])" \
  "$(<in.txt)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using Perl (assuming the file in question is named "in.txt") -

```
perl -e 'undef $/; while ($file=<>) {$file=~s/\n\n(.*)(\n\n)/\n$1\n/g; print $file}' in.txt
```

Basically, read in the whole file as a single string in Perl and then apply the substitution function in Perl to the whole string.

(Note - I have assumed that this is a Unix system. You might want to add an extra optional check for carriage returns for Windows machines as per @Fleshgrinder 's answer.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that you were looking for a solution in Python.